# Как правильно профессионалы держат в голове кучу методов

Tags: java

Подскажите, подскажите, я только в начале пути, и первая проблема - сложно удержать в голове более-менее сложную программу, когда в классе штук 15 методов, классов несколько и т.д.

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, как это всё происходит в реальной жизни, особенно, когда программа очень большая, промышленная, хаб какой-нибудь по приёмке сотен тонн груза и т.д.

Рисовать блок-схемы? Или как может есть какие-то видеоуроки, задайте вектор, пожалуйста, как правильно создать схему или что-то в этом роде

Comment: А не надо её удерживать, надо уметь ориентироваться в коде по надобности (при этом, естественно, иметь адекватно структурированный код) и иметь более-менее внятную документацию. Достаточно крупные проекты ни один человек не сможет удержать в голове целиком (хотя «штук 15 методов» и «классов несколько» это очень мало, в лично моей голове такое помещается без особых проблем)

Comment: Сложные приложения строятся на каких то принципах. Каких то архитектурных паттернах. Имеет какие то закономернсти. 
Вам не нужно эти принципы знать, для того, чтобы разбираться в приложении. Но для этого не надо помнить все классы всех модулей - надо только знать принцип модульности и то, как функционал распределен по модулям. Зная это, вы можете быстро найти нужный вам класс. Если же вам надо помнить 15 классов для одной задачи, то у вас вероятно проблемы с качеством кода.

Comment: Комментарии добавляйте